# How to show that alle graphs share a point

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm currently preparing for my exams and I do not this question, could someone explain it to me?

$f(x)= \sqrt{px-4p+4}$, the graph has $5$ 'branches' left, and $5$ on the right.
Now these all come together at a certain point, and the question is what point exactly.
Here's what the answer sheet tells me:

$f(x)= \sqrt{px-4p+4}  =  \sqrt{p(x-4)+4}$

$x=4 \leadsto  f(4) = \sqrt{ p(4-4)+4} = \sqrt4 = 2$, so the particular point is $(4,2)$

My question is how and why they take $x=4$ to solve the equation, and I think I am just seeing the wood for the trees and it's really simple, but I just can not seem to understand why.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words, you have a family of curves, one for each value of $p$, and the question is what point is on every curve in the family.  So you want to find a point that satisfies the equation no matter what $p$ is.

Once you simplify the equation as they have done, you can see that the coefficient of $p$ inside the square root is $(x-4)$; thus when $x=4$, $p$ will vanish and so the function value *at that point* is the same regardless of what value $p$ has.